# I have an issue with SAMBA file copy

Tags: networking, packet

Trying to reproduce the error in order to be able to handle it, but I am not sure what exactly what is going on...

Have been trying different things to resolve the issue:
1 Tryed to create the ip-conflict in case someone enabled DHCP Service on their service
2 Tryed to overload the network and cause packet collisions
3 Tryed to reconfigure the browser to timeout, but that is not it definately...

Tack Trace:

```
    Transport1 timedout waiting for response to
    SmbComReadAndX[
    command=SMB_COM_READ_ANDX,
    received=false,
    errorCode=0,
    flags=0x0018,
    flags2=0xC807,
    signSeq=945774,
    tid=45060,
    pid=65080,
    uid=22530,
    mid=833,
    wordCount=12,
    byteCount=0,
    andxCommand=0xFF,
    andxOffset=0,
    fid=49167,
    offset=21504,
    maxCount=1024,
    minCount=1024,
    openTimeout=-1,
    remaining=0,
    offset=21504
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a network issue because from what I see is the read packet that the issue is happening is fine.
Check server network card and cables.